# Is memory.limit() broken?

Tags: r

I run `memory.limit()` on my 48G Windows 10 machine and it returned 1.759219e+13. This is head scratching. I am using R 3.6.1.

Is `memory.limit()` broken? Any other way to obtain memory limit?

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Comment: Try posting the contents of `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [issue with RStudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4986) (hopefully fixed in the next update). It works well in RGui.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `disk.frame::df_ram_size()` instead. It works on Windows 10 with RStudio and R 3.6.1.

You can install `disk.frame` using `install.packages("disk.frame")`

Comment: so where is it?  GitHub?  r-forge?  If it's not public anywhere, then this answer isn't actually too useful ...